# Overwrite keys from array by another arrays values

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, array-map

I have two arrays. The array "texts" and the array "dbTexts". In "dbTexts" all texts of a certain category are in my database.

A record looks something like this:

```
0 => {
   id: 1
   de: "German text"
   en: "English text"
   name: "question"
},
1 => {
   id: 2
   de: "German text"
   en: "English text"
   name: "error"
},
2 => {
   id: 3
   de: "German text"
   en: "English text"
   name: "success"
},
```

Now I want to manipulate the $texts array and add a key/value for every element of the $dbTexts array.

I want the keys of $texts to be the "name" key of $dbTexts and the value should be either the "de" key or the "en" key.

What I've tried:

```
$texts = array_map(function ($key) {
     return $texts[$key['name']] = $key[app()->getLocale()];
},$dbTexts->toArray());
```

`app()->getLocale()` automatically returns "de" or "en".

So $key would be every element of $dbTexts.

`$texts[$key['name']]` should return 'question' in the first example record and `$key[app()->getLocale()]` should return the de/en value of each element.

The output I want to have is:

```
$texts = [
 'question' => 'German text',
 'error' => 'German text',
 'success' => 'German text',
]
```

This whole de/en thing isn't important for this question. It's more that I want to create the $texts variable which will hold the "name" of every $dbText as a key and the associated value of de/en from the current $dbText.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most easily achieved with a simple `foreach` loop:

```
foreach ($dbTexts->toArray() as $text) {
    $texts[$text['name']] = $text[app()->getLocale()];
}
```

Simplified [demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/OpmCp)

An alternate solution would be to use [`array_column`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to re-index the array:

```
$texts = array_column($dbTexts->toArray(), app()->getLocale(), 'name');
```

Simplified [demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/MPDeF)

Comment: ugh... i didn't want to write a foreach... too bad, thought with array_map, it would be an elegant solution

Comment: @JuniorDev the problem with `array_map` is that the keys of the output array are always the same as the input array, and you want to get different keys.

Comment: @JuniorDev see my edit - I've added a neater solution (although it will be slower) using `array_column`